# Are torchlight 2 and 3 work together?

Tags: torchlight

I am wanting to play this with a friend but he wants Torchlight 3 and I want Torchlight 2- if he does get this from the game pass, can we still play together or is that not even possible? I am assuming the latter, but wanted to check- have not looked into 3. We did try with 2- but for some reason, he could not connect even after we changed the port from 0 to another # that he found out about and saved the file in the gaming folder and restarted the computer and game we still could not "hook up".

The reason I say all of this is we want like 4 or 5 other of our friends to join on the private server option.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't play together as the two iterations of the game are incompatible with each other as they are completely separate games. If you all want to play together, you must all be playing Torchlight 2 or Torchlight 3. Not both or a mix; it's one or the other.

It's like trying to play Halo 1 multiplayer with Halo 4 (Master Chief Collection does not count).